# Difference between std::is_signed<T> and std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, numeric-limits

Both `std::is_signed<T>` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` are supposed to give answers about the signedness of `T`.
Why are there now **two** indicators for signedness (i.e. since C++11)?

Comment: `std::is_signed<T>` is a type, while the `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` member is just a value. In meta-programming, having the former is much more convenient, and is also more consistent.

Comment: Well you'd actually use `std::is_signed<T>::value` in practice. Where would you use `std::is_signed<T>` directly?

Comment: But is do they their results ever differ?

Comment: @Kevin: How much meta-programming have you done with type-traits?

Comment: @KevinBallard, you often want to pass a metafunction such as `is_signed` to another metafunction, such as `apply` or `and_` rather than inspecting the "result" (i.e. its `value` member) immediately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that the only difference is if `std::numeric_limits<T>` is specialized for a user-defined type. Such a user-defined type could of course provide their own value for `is_signed`. But asking for `std::is_signed<T>::value` on this type will always return `false` unless `std::is_signed<T>` has been independently specialized.

It seems as though the condition that `std::is_signed<T>` represents is

```
is_arithmetic<T>::value && T(-1) < T(0)
```

---

**Update**: The always-knowledgable Howard Hinnant [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305723/difference-between-stdis-signedt-and-stdnumeric-limitstis-signed/15305830#comment21604593_15305830) that while `std::numeric_limits<>` can be legally-specialized, nothing in `<type_traits>` is allowed to be specialized unless otherwise specified, and `is_signed` is not specified as being specializable.

Therefore, `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` *may* return `true` for a user-defined type (if it's been specialized) but `std::is_signed<T>::value` will always return `false` for user-defined types.

Comment: Can you specialize `std::numeric_limits<T>` for a user-defined type? In C++03 it was illegal for the user to add anything to namespace `std`. Has that restriction been lifted for C++11?

Comment: @DavidHammen: No, the restriction is there, but it doesn't apply to specializations. You're allowed to specialize existing templates in `std`, you just can't add your own stuff.

Comment: @DavidHammen : It's always been legal to fully specialize templates in namespace `std`, just not to partially specialize class templates or overload functions/function templates.

Comment: @DavidHammen: `std::numeric_limits` and `std::swap` are both examples of templates that you are encouraged to specialize as appropriate.

Comment: @ildjarn: IIRC, partial specialization of class templates was not problematic.

Comment: @Xeo : Ah, could be, I was going by memory – possibly I was just thinking of overloading function templates.

Comment: This is really close to the right answer.  It is legal to specialize `numeric_limits` for your own type, because chapter 17 says you can and 18.3.2 does not say otherwise.  But [meta.type.synop]/p1 says you can't specialize anything in `<type_traits>` unless otherwise specified and [meta.unary.prop] does not specify otherwise for `is_signed`.  `is_signed` will **always** be false for a class type.  `numeric_limits` **could** be true for a non-std class type if specialized.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Excellent info. I just put it in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Xeo has also made the excellent point that `is_signed` is an `integral_constant<bool, value>`, where as `numeric_limits::is_signed` isn't.  And tag dispatching on functions overloaded with `integral_constant` is a common idiom.  So in that context `is_signed` is the preferred tool.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: given C++11 defines `is_signed<T>::value` as `is_arithmetic<T>::value && T(-1) < T(0)`, doesn't the spec allow -- perhaps even require -- `is_signed` to not work if `T` is a class type not `constexpr`-constructible from an `int`?  (Mutatis mutandis for `is_unsigned`.)  Not to say this is a _useful_ definition of `is_signed`.  But if I'm trying to write portable code (or to implement a clone of `<type_traits>` that I can swap out for the real deal when I have compiler support), can I truly expect `struct S {}; static_assert(!std::is_signed<S>::value, "");` to compile?

Comment: Aha!  Just found DR2197 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2197 which requires what I wrote to work.  Given the comment there about existing implementation behavior, I think I can work from the fixed semantics.